# Could you give an example of an injective function $f:\mathbb{Z_+}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z_+}$ for an integer $n$ s.t. $2\leq n$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

We know that both of the domain the the co-domain are countable sets, so there is a bijection between them, Is there any SIMPLE injection?

Here is some injection which I thougt of, but It turns out to be  very complicated!

Define $g_i$ to be the $i$-th prime number. so $g_1=2$ , $g_2=3$, $g_3=5$, $g_4=7$ ,$g_5=11$,...

For each positive integer $n$ greater than $1$, define  the function $G^n$ recursively to be $n$-ary function s.t. $G^n(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)=g_{i_1}^{G^{n-1}(i_2,i_3,...,i_n)}   $ where $i_j$ is a positive integer for $1\leq j \leq n$

and $G^2(i,j)={g_i}^{g_j}$

We denote $G^n(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)$ as $G(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)$ and the arity is clear from context ( we do this only to make it readable)

and we let the function $f$ to be $G$ which seems to be an injective function.

Any more interesting and more simple  examples?

Comment: What about just $(a,b,c)\mapsto 2^a 3^b 5^c $ ? That's injective.

Comment: @amcalde, cool! this is a nice injection, but can generalize it to any arity using more primes :)

Comment: Yes you can use any $n$ primes for that. It's the first thing I thought of even before I read to your example.

Comment: @amcalde, It's a nice example in fact, but as nowdays, I'm studying mathematical logic and we use recursive definitions much, I though of defining such a function recursively, this will be clearer when you consider that I wanted such function in a context of a problem of logic! anyway, could you provide an answer to close the question?

Comment: It should be noted that $[X]^n$ is the set of all subsets of $X$ of size exactly $n$; not the set of $n$-tuples which is $X^n$. In the case of $\Bbb N$ (or any "naturally ordered set") we can think about that as the set of $n$-tuples which are strictly increasing in order. If you did mean the set of $n$-tuples of natural numbers, you should perhaps use $\Bbb Z_+^n$ instead of brackets like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I didn't know that such brackets have a special meaning. I meant the set of all $n$-tuples. I will change it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $n$, pick $n$ distinct primes: $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$. Let $f$ act as follows:
$$(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto p_1^{x_1} p_2^{x_2} \cdots p_n^{x_n}$$
This is a simple injective function from $[\Bbb{Z}^+]^n$ to $[\Bbb{Z}^+]$ as required.

Comment: I think You should  add the condition that those primes are distinct :) otherwise, it's not an injection, is it?

Comment: Please note [my comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952645/could-you-give-an-example-of-an-injective-function-f-mathbbzn-rightarro#comment1960630_952645) to the main question!